# JavaScript Mountain Daylight Saving Time odd behavior

Tags: javascript, date, time, momentjs

I receive a date from a DB which has a time in UTC format.
The date is irrelevant for me I just need the hours and minutes.

**Problem**

When I sent the date to the Data Base I convert it from local time to UTC with this function:

```
self.toUTC = function (date) {

    var now = new Date(date);       
    var utc = new Date(now.getTime() + now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

    return utc;
};
```

When I look in the developer tools from Chrome I see this:

[image]

Oddly when I receive the date from the Data Base and convert it back to local time, it grabs the correct GMT for Denver which is GMT -0600 because of the Daylight Savings Time. I use this function for it:

```
//converts date to just time in utc format to include in menu
self.setTimeForMenu = function (dateUTC) {

    var date = new Date(dateUTC + ' UTC');          

    var hours = (date.getHours()<10?'0':'') + date.getHours();
    var minutes = (date.getMinutes()<10?'0':'') + date.getMinutes();

    return hours + ':' + minutes;
};
```

And when I see the dates on the Chrome Developer tools I see this:

[image]

**What I've tried**

1. Combinations of the above JavaScript Functions
2. moment.js but I got the same results

Do any of you have suggestions for what I should do next ?

**EDIT 1**
If I use now.toUTCString() or now.toISOString() it doesn't change anything because when I grab the date and set it in a new Date JavaScript object it already sets it to GMT -0700:

[image]

Comment: What does `now.getTimezoneOffset()` return? Same thing in all browsers?

Comment: Yes 420 for all browsers which means the GMT -0700

Comment: Can you show a sample usage of how you want to use your `toUTC()` function? I don't think such function is necessary. You can just use the [getUTCHours()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCHours) and [getUTCMinutes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMinutes) to get the UTC time..

Comment: nice question with photos and what  you tried.  I like.

Comment: @euther You didn't show the code that would want to use the `toUTC()` function. Please show code using toUTC that doesn't behave correctly.

Comment: @JuanMendes I just want the `toUTC()` to grab the Date in the current local timezone in this case -0600 instead of -0700

Comment: @euther I asked you to post code because I think your question is unclear. Please don't just regurgitate what you already mentioned. I think your code has some bad assumptions. What you are showing on the screen is the `toString()` which is not something you should be coding against. Again, please post code that anyone can run, showing the wrong behavior, and it should not just be printing the `toString()`, you should be using the methods I mentioned to get data out of your date object. Best thing is to create a http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

When you send a date back to the server, you should send it as an ISO UTC string, just use

[`date.toISOString();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

If you need to display UTC times, you can just use  `date.getUTCHours()` or  `date.getUTCMinutes()`

I don't think there is a need for conversion of a JS Date to UTC. That is, JS doesn't allow you to create a date in a specific locale (UTC, or any other), only the one your computer is set to. That is, `getTimeZoneOffset()` is always for local time.

Comment: still getting the date in GMT -0700, please see my edit for more information